# How to convert date format into string in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to get date and time of received and sent messages . I used deviceTimestamp() method of Message class but this returns obj of QDateTime but I want this in String . So could anyone please tell me how should I do this or any other way of getting message time and date ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you obtain your QDateTime, can't use the toString() method?

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html#toString

```
QString dateString = yourQDateTime.toString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
```